# Organising php files for many different ajax requests

Tags: php, ajax, organization

I have a single web page that makes a lot of ajax requests to php.

I believe that the best way to do this is to have a a single php file (controller) that handles all of these requests and loads of very short php files that get included depending on the request.

Is this the best way to go about doing this or should I just lump all functions into one php file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

that depends, because if responses to requests are short and can be grouped by function within a single file it would be desirable depending on the conditions by request, call the function in specific, clearly this is not the best practice, right would like you explain above, through a php file as controller handle the request and load the file that corresponds to the same.

I hope I've helped a little...

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty much they way I would do it.

Personally I tend to have a directory of files each of which have a function within them which returns an array of operations they respond to and the function that the controller should call.

so in module_a.php there is a function module_a_operations(), returning the detail of what the file handles.

```
array(
   "delete_file" => "module_a_delete_file"
);
```

That might be overkill depending on the size of the application.